# Secured Httponly cookies for multiple services

Tags: docker, cookies, authorization, microservices

I have an identity service which issues http-only cookies, used for authorization requests. This identity service is totally/physically separated from other services of my site, that is it is dockerised. Other services are dockerised as well. With my current settings, I see that this authorization cookie is not sent to other services. So, my question is, if it technically possible for multiple physically separated services to share one and the same secured/http-only cookie?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely. Check the `domain` and `path` attributes of cookies. If you have services on subdomains as in `service1.example.com`, `service2.example.com` and `authserver.example.com` etc., set the domain attribute of the cookie as `example.com`. With this setting, if the cookie is set for a client, the client will send the cookie with every request to all services.